# Checkbox clicked style appears for all the checkboxes when i press dropdown option through useState in a different page in React/Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

So I have these sets of checkboxes for 3 different categories. 1 is "types", 1 is "Price" and the other is "Categories". they work perfectly. I have created a separate checkbox component and data is passed there without any problem.

**The problem is when I click the checkbox and data is rendered but when I click the dropdown in the index page once and then press it again the data is the same as expected but the clicked style by that I mean"checked" is applied to all the checkboxes. is there any way to overcome this?**

**this is the separate checkbox component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  isChecked?: boolean;
  handleClick?: any;
  label: string;
  className?: string;
  labelClassName: string;
  handleChange?: any
}

const Checkbox = ({isChecked,handleClick,label,labelClassName,handleChange}: Props) => {
  const [checking,setChecking]=useState(isChecked)
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={label}
        checked={checking}
        onClick={()=>{handleClick();setChecking(!checking)}}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={`space-x-3 text-gray-400 bg-gray-800 border rounded border-stone-200 $`}
      />
      <label className={labelClassName} htmlFor={label}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Checkbox;
```

**Main Index Page**

```
// these states are for dropdown/dropup styling
const [categoryOpts, setCategoryOpts]= useState(true);
const [typeOpts, setTypeOpts]= useState(true);
const [priceOpts, setPriceOpts]= useState(true);

 const [checking,setChecking]=useState(false)
    const handleCheckChange=()=>{
        setChecking(!checking)
    }
index (){
<div>
// this is for showing/hiding price option
<div className='flex justify-between cursor-pointer' onClick={()=>setPriceOpts(!priceOpts)}>
<Text as='h5' tag='h2'>
Price
</Text>
{priceOpts?
<dropdown icon up/>
</svg> :
<dropdown icon down>
</svg>
}
</div>
// price option mapping that comes from api source.
{ priceOpts? 
<div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
{checkboxes.map(({ label, onClick, key }) => 
<div key={key}>
<Checkbox 
labelClassName='text-sm text-gray-400 ml-3'
label={label}
handleClick={onClick}
isChecked={checking}
handleChange={handleCheckChange}
/>
</div>
)}                    
</div>: ''
}
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Checkbox
  labelClassName="text-sm text-gray-400 ml-3"
  label={label}
  handleClick={onClick}
  isChecked={checking} // this is the problem
  handleChange={handleCheckChange}
/>;
```

You're setting `checking` prop using the same value for all your checkboxes in the main index page.

You need to have a `checking` parameter for each checkbox that you're rendering

`{checkboxes.map(({ label, onClick, key })` right here. It should contain the state on whether the checkbox is checked or not. Like this

`{checkboxes.map(({ label, onClick, key, checking })`

You have to rework your checkboxes structure and checkbox even handling

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing is that data that is coming is like { key, onclick, label } and there is no checking prop. even if I try to declare a Type or interface and push it in. it gives an error.